# Rep on meta.webmasters.stackexchange is just a mirror of rep on webmasters.stackexchange

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

My rep on this site is currently 211, it should be 121. Every time I gain reputation on the private beta, its reflected here as well.

It also doesn't look like the 100 rep bonus is calculated into my score:

```
total votes: 2
 2        30 (10)
 2        30 (10)
-- 2010-07-09 rep +20   = 21        

** total rep 21 :)

days represented 0
rep cap was reached on 0 days
rep cap was exceeded on 0 days
```

Where it does appear to be considered correctly on the beta:

```
total votes: 13
-- bonuses   (100)
 2       451 (10)
 2       460 (10)
 2       471 (10)
 2       474 (10)
 2       478 (5)
 2       478 (5)
 2       478 (5)
 2       460 (10)
 2       471 (10)
 2       460 (10)
 1       460 (15)
 2       478 (5)
 2       478 (5)
-- 2010-07-09 rep +110  = 211       

** total rep 211 :)

days represented 0
rep cap was reached on 0 days
rep cap was exceeded on 0 days
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`status-bydesign`

From the meta.webmasters FAQ:

> Reputation here is entirely derived from the parent website, and **synchronized hourly**. Your reputation here is the same as your reputation on the parent website. Votes here do not affect your reputation on the parent site. However, you can earn badges here on the meta site.

Comment: That will teach me to not assume the FAQ is the 'same as usual' and actually read it :)

Comment: This is actually very clever, they've preempted the creation of more quagmires like meta.stackoverflow.com by not allowing the reputation junkies to get their fix here. Good move!